# Show that coefficients of $f$ are integral over $R$, if $f(t)$ is integral over $R[t]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I am stuck on this Algebra exercise, which is:

"Let $R$ be a domain and $K$ its field of fractions. Let $t$ be transcendental over $K$ and consider $f(t) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}a_n t^n \in K[t]$. Show that, if $f(t)$ is integral over $R[t]$, then $a_n$ is integral over $R$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$."

To be honest, I'm not even sure if I understood the definitions needed for this exercise correctly, so could you maybe correct me?

I understand it like this: $K$ can be seen as an $R$-algebra, so $K[t]$ is an $R[t]$-algebra. Because $t$ is  transcendental, it means that $P(t) \neq 0$ for every polynomial $P \in K[X]$, so especially $f(t) \neq 0$. If $f(t) \in K[t]$ is integral over $R[t]$, this means that there is a polynomial $g(X) = b_0 + b_1X + ... + b_{m-1}X^{m-1} + X^m$, with $b_i \in R[t]$, such that $g(f(t)) = 0$. These $b_i$ are not $0$ as well, since $R[t] \subseteq K[t]$. Now we want to show that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a polynomial $p_n \in R[X]$, such that $p_n(a_n) = 0$ and the last coefficient of $p_n$ is $1$, which is the definition of $a_n$ being integral over $R$. Is this correct so far?

Now I don't know how to proceed. Can someone give me a hint how to prove this? Maybe $g$ can be manipulated in some way?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: You are correct so far. Here we use the first observation you have, that if $P(t) = 0$ then $P$ is identically 0. Note that $g(f(t)) = 0.$ So we need to build a polynomial in $K[t]$ out of $g(f(t)).$

After we simplify $g(f(t))$ we obviously get some polynomial $P \in K[t]$, and so that polynomial must kill $t$ and ergo be identically 0.

$P$ has constant coefficient $b_0 + b_1a_0^1 + b_2a_0^2 + \cdots + b_{m-1}a_0^{m-1}+ a_0^m,$ which must thus be equal to 0. Therefore $a_0$ is integral.

Can you figure out how to turn that $P$ has all 0 coefficients into a polynomial relation in $a_1$? Try inducting, and proving the $a_i$ are algebraic one at a time.

Comment: Ok, i have proven that they are algebraic, but how can i now show that they are integral?

Comment: No, i noticed that i havent even proved that they are algebraic, because i dont know if the polynomials that i get are non-zero, this is frustrating ;(